# Mysql syntax for selecting data across two tables?

Tags: mysql

I want to select titles and dates from all documents that mention "Africa." I have two tables:

mentioned_places table:

```
|  name  | in_document | 
------------------------
| Africa | 10001.xml   | 
| Africa | 10002.xml   |
```

documents table:

```
| filename  | title | date       | 
----------------------------------
| 10001.xml | Foo   | 2013-01-01 | 
| 10002.xml | Bar   | 2013-01-02 |
```

I know I can look up the file name first, then look up the title and date, but I'd like to do it all in one query. For instance, I can do this (not real code; it's really rough):

```
SELECT in_document FROM mentioned_places WHERE name="$mentionedPlace";
```

and then

```
SELECT DISTINCT title, date FROM documents WHERE filename IN ($listOfFilenames);
```

...but I'd like to be able to do this all in one query. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT d.title, d.date 
  FROM documents d JOIN mentioned_places p
    ON d.filename = p.in_document
 WHERE p.name = 'Africa'
 GROUP BY d.title, d.date
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.title, d.date 
  FROM documents d JOIN mentioned_places p
    ON d.filename = p.in_document
 WHERE p.name = 'Africa'
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7feb6/3)** demo

Comment: Instead of `GROUP BY d.title, d.date ` simply use `DISTINCT` ?? :)

Comment: I don't think that he's been rude. RTFM isn't rude per se. He even quoted you the relevant section :)

Comment: @hims056 I weren't. I'm sorry that you felt that way. Let me fix it and rephrase.

Comment: @hims056 As per mysql documentation *In most cases, a DISTINCT clause can be considered as a special case of GROUP BY.* But it can be done this way for sure. Thanks for your input,  specifically added your  version in the updated answer.

Comment: And now I know about SQLFiddle, which is awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.title, d.date FROM documents AS d JOIN mentioned_places AS m ON m.in_document = d.filename WHERE m.name = '$mentionedPlace'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use "JOIN"

```
SELECT mentioned_places.name, documents.title, documents.date FROM mentioned_places join documents ON mentioned_places.in_document=documents.filename;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
SELECT p.in_document, d.title, d.date 
FROM mentioned_pleaces p join documents d
ON p.in_document = d.filename 
WHERE p.name = "$mentionedPlace" AND d.filename IN ($listOfFilenames);
```